# Creating a Loop from a Recorded Macro

Tags: excel, find, vba

I have 2 sets of data that have to be matched based on one identifier that they both have in common (Range 1 is on Sheet1 and it runs from Column A:F, Range2 is on Sheet3 and runs from Column A:M).  The matching values for both ranges will occur in Column E for Sheet1 and Column C for Sheet3. I tried to record a macro to see if I could create a simple loop to just repeat what I was doing until it ran into any irregular data, but I ran into the issue of how to loop the actions that I was doing.  Here is my code:

```
Sub Record_And_Destroy() 
    'first issue is writing a loop that will cycle through all rows in column E
    'starting in row 18 in this example
    Range("E18").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    'Sheet3 contains the second table of data 
    'I want to search based on the copied value from Sheet1...
    *Cells.Find(What:="03885740-131601", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate*
    'The data that is being matched is in column C of Sheet3 but I need all columns A:M that
    'are associated with the found match
    Range("A10:M10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("G18").Select
    'Column G is the next available column when matching to Sheet1 so every other selection
    'would be placed in Column G but the row would differ based upon
    'which row was being searched
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    'this way I clean up the data base to only contain the "problem" cases
End Sub
```

Question 1: is there a way to use Cells.Find to search for the selection as opposed to the value?

Question 2: In the event that the loop found no matches, is there a way to format rows G:S on Sheet1 to display a red background so that I would know to go back and check those values once the loop had concluded?

Comment: If you have Excel 2010 or higher you can reference another worksheet in a formula for a conditional formatting rule to color Sheet1's non-matching rows red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to go down column E (starting at row 18) and search each value to see if it exists in Sheet3's column C. If it exists then copy that row on Sheet3 from column A to column M and put it into Sheet1 starting at column G on the same row currently being examined.

```
Sub Record_And_Destroy()
    Dim rw As Long, mrw As Long, ws3 As Worksheet

    Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For rw = 18 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            If CBool(Application.CountIf(ws3.Columns(3), .Cells(rw, "E").Value)) Then
                mrw = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, "E"), ws3.Columns(3), 0)
                ws3.Cells(mrw, "A").Resize(1, 13).Copy _
                  Destination:=.Cells(rw, "G")
                ws3.Rows(mrw).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next rw
    End With

    Set ws3 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note that I've completely avoided the use of `.Select` in favor of direct worksheet and cell addressing. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goal(s).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and it worked perfectly! Thank you for your help! I will keep this example on-file for future similar cases. You're amazing!